# Cohomology with compact support and the nerve of a recouvrement

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, simplicial-complexes

Let $X$ be a simplicial complexe and we assume it localy finite and finite dimensional. We suppose taht there exist a simplicial complexe $Y$ and a map assigning to each vertex $s\in Y$ a finite subcomplex $X_{s}$ of $X$ such that the collection $\mathcal{Y}=(X_{s})_{s\in Y}$ is a covering by closed subsets of $X$ and the nerve of this covering $\mathcal{Y}$ is isomorphic to the simplicial complexe $Y$.

My question is : It is true that $H_{c}^{p}(X,\mathbb{Z})\simeq\bigoplus_{s\in Y}H^{p}(X_{s},\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_{c}^{p}(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ ?

where $H_{c}^{\bullet}$ is the cohomoloy with compact support.

Comment: I retagged this question (not sure if overly well though), but then I still think it is an improvement over the old tag, which was '10'. I am not sure this is what happened, but perhaps: please do not use the numbers written next to the tags instaed of the name of the tag itself. The number (in the selection list) indicates *only* the number of times the tag was used so far it is *not* 'the number of the tag'. Using it as tag thus makes little sense.    

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding something, or the answer is obviously no. Take $X=S^1$ triangulated with three 1-simplices. Consider $Y=\Delta^1$, let $X_0$ be some 1-simplex of $X$, and let $X_1$ be the union of the other two 1-simplices of $X$. Then $H^1_c(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, yet each of $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_0 \cap X_1$, and $Y$ has no cohomology in degree 1 (and $Y$ is compact). Nevertheless, for results related to what you are asking, perhaps you want to look at some kind of Mayer-Vietoris spectral sequence. However, such a spectral sequence usually does not directly involve the cohomology of $Y$.

Comment: By the way, here is an interesting common example. When each $X_s$ is contractible, then $X\simeq Y$ and so the cohomology of $X$ is isomorphic to the cohomology of $Y$. Nevertheless, their cohomologies with compact support may still be quite different.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, but the formula is true for some particular examples. For example, if $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with vertex vertex $w\in\mathbb{Z}$ and edges $\{n,n+1\}$, and the recouvrement is by the edges $\{n,n+1\}$. The formula is also true for another complicated examples : one dimensional complexes above the Bruhat-Tits tree of the p-adique group $PGL(2,F)$.

Comment: I think if we pute the addionnal condition :
a) For all $s,t\in Y$, the sub-complexes $X_{s}$ and $X{t}$ are isomorphic.
b) $X$ is chamber complexe.

Then the formula is true.